# OS independent threading in C++?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading

Is it possible to implement OS independent threading model of User Level Threads (ULT) in C/C++? In other words, can we break down a process logically into ULTs and dynamically make switches in between them?

Comment: You might want to look into what I got when I asked this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298986/is-there-something-to-replace-the-ucontext-h-functions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boost.Thread offers a fair amount of abstraction for cross-platform threading.

Comment: And in the upcoming C++0x standard, you automatically have OS-independent threads with `std::thread`

Comment: Oh, good to know this. So it will be a language feature like java?

Comment: @mihsathe, @Charles Saliva, <pedantic>It's more a library feature than a language feature.</pedantic>

Comment: @zneak, <pedantic>The C++ language standard (ISO/IEC 14882) includes the language's standard library.  The updated C++ language standard will include a larger standard library.</pedantic>

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen Got me on that. But I'm pretty sure it isn't the case for Java.

Comment: Part of the threading support in C++0x is made up of core language features too though (the memory model, for example), so even if you ignored the library parts, it'd still be a language feature. :)

Answer (score 3):

Just use POSIX threads. There's a reasonably conformant implementation for Windows if you need to support Windows.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I was asking about the implementation. Is it possible to implement ULTs?

Comment: @mihsathes, ultimately threads and processes are a service provided by the operating system.  To spawn a new thread requires access to an OS-specific API (or a wrapper library which talks to the OS)

Comment: @Charles then what's the difference in implementation of Kernel Level Thread(KLT) and User Level Thread(ULT) then?

Comment: There's no *portable* way to implement ULT. The closest thing is the deprecated `makecontext` interface (which depends on POSIX+XSI option and may be removed from future versions of the standard entirely). Another old popular method was setting up a custom signal-handling stack, raising a signal, and calling `setjmp` inside the signal handler to make a new "thread context". This method may work but it's an extremely ugly hack and it's explicitly frowned upon by POSIX (it's considered UB).

Comment: By the way, it should be noted that as of POSIX 2008, threads are no longer an optional feature in POSIX but a mandatory one, so if you're looking towards the future, anything that depends on deprecated/slated-for-removal features or implementation-specific hacks will almost surely result in *less portability* (from a practical standpoint) than just using POSIX threads. If you really want cooperative threading semantics, it's easy to implement that on top of POSIX threads using barriers or condition variables.

Answer (score 1):

OpenMP is a nice way to handle threads for many common use cases.

Answer (score 1):

In C, one somewhat portable (it requires POSIX) user-level threading library is [GNU Pth](http://www.gnu.org/software/pth/).  It uses cooperation instead of preemption, and implements per-thread stack and other structures in user space.  As expected, this will *not* provide the same performance characteristics as OS-level threading.  However, it does provide some of the same abstractions.

Answer (score 1):

On windows 7 there is a way to implement your own User Mode Scheduler:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd627187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

This is basecally an API to make a User Mode Threads using a User Mode Scheduler and the best thing is opening process explorer and see Kernel Time 0.

Hwever I know people who implemented successfully the UMS but the microsoft reported some errors on the api . . .

Comment: How is this in any way "OS independent"? It isn't even available on all common versions of Windows!

Comment: It isn't, but it his the only way to make User Mode Threads, no other OS have something like this, i dont think that POSIX are able to mix Kernel Threads with user Threads, this API does do that xD. That i know it's the only way to successful implement ums threads but i dont know it all XD.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look at ZThread is a cross platform c++ library.

Thinking in c++ vol 2 uses this library to explain multi-threading application.