# Closing a file after a segmentation fault occurs in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have a simple program running with a logger file open throughout the duration of the process. I researched online and it said that files automatically close when the `exit()` function is called or the `main` function returns. However, it says nothing about if a program crashes during execution.

Therefore, is there a way I can manually, or even automatically, close a file after the program crashes?

Comment: Although [as mentioned by others], the OS will close the files (but _not_ handle flushing of `FILE *` streams), generally, once you get a segfault, there's little you can do _meaningfully_. See my answer: [C handle signal SIGFPE and continue execution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39432614/5382650) for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modern operating systems will automatically clean up OS resources like files and allocated memory, so the file will be closed after a crash like this. However if using standard library I/O (FILE* or even C low-level file descriptors) there may be buffered writes that are not yet part of the operating system's view of the file. Those unbuffered writes are most likely simply gone.

However, the more generally accepted correct answer is to code in such a way that you will not have such exceptions to begin with.

Comment: If I use `fflush` every time I write to the logger, those unbuffered writes will be put on the file, right?

Comment: You can skip the calls to `fflush` and simply set the stream to be unbuffered via `setbuf(file, NULL);`.