# How to know if my signal handler is interrupting an async-signal-unsafe function?

Tags: c, unix, signals, setjmp

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7335085/578749), I can only `longjmp()` out of a signal handler if it is not calling an `async-signal-unsafe` function. Is there a reliable way to know, from inside the signal handler, if the process was executing a non `async-signal-unsafe` function at the moment of the signal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious answer is that, after calling `setjmp`, don't call any *async-signal-unsafe* functions. Then you know for sure.

Note that [`setjmp(3)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/longjmp.3.html) (Linux) has a slightly more specific definition for when the Undefined Behaviour occurs, and offers two ways to avoid it:

> POSIX.1-2008 Technical Corrigendum 2 adds longjmp() and
> siglongjmp() to the list of async-signal-safe functions.
> However, the standard recommends avoiding the use of these
> functions from signal handlers and goes on to point out that if
> these functions are called from a signal handler that interrupted
> a call to a non-async-signal-safe function (or some equivalent,
> such as the steps equivalent to exit(3) that occur upon a return
> from the initial call to main()), **the behavior is undefined if
> the program subsequently makes a call to a non-async-signal-safe
> function**.  The only way of avoiding undefined behavior is to
> ensure one of the following:

> After long jumping from the signal handler, the program does
> not call any non-async-signal-safe functions and does not
> return from the initial call to main().

> Any signal whose handler performs a long jump must be blocked
> during every call to a non-async-signal-safe function and no
> non-async-signal-safe functions are called after returning
> from the initial call to main().

Emphasis is mine, and highlights that UB only occurs if you call another *async-signal-unsafe* (*non-async-signal-safe*) function after jumping, which differs slightly, but significantly, from the description you read in the other answer.

This is described even more succinctly in [`signal-safety(7)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html):

> If a signal handler interrupts the execution of an unsafe function, and the handler terminates via a call to longjmp(3) or siglongjmp(3) and the program subsequently calls an unsafe function, then the behavior of the program is undefined.